# Overriding existing JavaScript Array.prototype method causes infinite recursion?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know that `pop()` is a built in method in JavaScript arrays. I was just playing around and for kicks decided to override the built in prototype method and encountered this scenario and have no explanation to what is going under the hood.

When ran the code below in a Node REPL or from a file, it creates in an infinite recursion in my Windows 10 system. The version of Node I am running is v.8.9.1.

```js
Array.prototype.pop = function() {
  console.log(this);
}

const a = [1, 2, 3];

a.pop();
```

If someone can explain this phenomenon it would be amazing!

Comment: That code works as it should - it logs the array to the console

Comment: The code provided has no recursion when run as described.

Comment: Please try running the code in a REPL or a by running a node file with the code. It goes in an infinite recursion in my system for some reason. I am running Node v8.9.1,

Comment: [Can't repro on v9.7.1](https://repl.it/repls/KaleidoscopicMenacingMuse), but on my v9.0.0 I indeed hit an `Maximum call stack size exceeded` at *formatArray (util.js:737:17)*.

Comment: Can't find the sources, but the logical explanation is that `console.log` method calls `pop()` on an Array somewhere, and since this method itself calls console.log, you end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: I don't mean to get on my soapbox, but... _This is why you shouldn't modify globals!_

Comment: @Kaiido if you change the `console.log` become return, and do `console.log(a.pop())` it works as it should. No behaviour change in `console.log`. It shows `console.log` does not call `Array.pop()`

Comment: @NikkoKhresna try `Array.prototype.pop = function(){throw new Error('baz is not in the foo')}; console.log([1])`

Comment: Interesting @Kaiido. Can you try my code as well? https://tio.run/##JcxBCsIwEEDRfU4xywTagLoMLjyHuJjGqJGQGSbTQpGePVXcfh7/jQu2KJl1nHBKZax0T71fRHD1LKSkKyfPxHCGx1yjZqrWwccASNJZqtVXbi6YzZhItSngV14PAxwHON3Cv1JJvtDT4u9knQu97w

Comment: Why would that code not work. There is nothing related to the console.log from inside pop there.

Comment: I'll try find if node repo has issue related to this

Comment: Im as confused as you bro lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is something within node engine.

If I use V8 engine, it works as predicted.
https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/37GoKLFSr6AovyS/pLIgVa8gv0DBViGtNC@5JDM/T0NToZpLQSE5P684PydVLyc/XaMkI7NY05qrlosLJFqikAhUHm2oo2Cko2Aca82VCDJBQ/P/fwA

But not with node engine.

Plus:
If you change `pop` with `slice`, it works just fine regardless the engine.

So we might just deduce that it is a bug within node in `Array.prototype.pop`

Comment: Nope it's in console.log